# MIPS, ADDIU out of range in PCSPIM

Tags: mips, instruction-set, pcspim

I have the follow instruction, and I don't understand why the PCSPIM is giving me the following warning:

```
spim:(parser) immediate value (61440) out of rainge (-32768..32767)
on line 88 of file
   addiu $a, $zero, 0xF000
                    ^
```

I according to the [ISA](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html), I should have

```
Description: Adds a register and a sign-extended immediate value and
stores the result in a register

Operation: $t = $s + imm; advance_pc(4);

Syntax: addiu $t, $s, imm 

Encoding: 0010 01ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

If I convert addiu $a0, $zero, 0xF000 into machine code I would have

```
opcode | rs  | rt   | imm val
-------+-----+------+--------------------
0010 01|00 00|0 0100| 1111 0000 0000 0000
```

which should fit the instruction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you meant something like this:

```
    addiu    $a0,$zero,0xF000
```

This is a quirk of `spim` because it is *not* treating this as a pseudo-op. But, given this, it is *correct* to flag this.

Regardless of whether you use `addi` or `addiu` they *both* have the same *signed* range of `-32768 to 32767`. The only difference is whether the instruction will generate an exception on integer overflow. That is, both instructions will do sign extend on the immediate value and *not* do sign extend for `addi` and zero extend for `addiu`.

Your value `0xF000` is 61440 [decimal] which is outside the allowable range for the instructions. In both cases, you'll get a *sign extended* value of `0xFFFFF000`

`spim` saw the `0xF000` and recognized that you wanted to add `0x0000F000` and *not* `0xFFFFF000` but wouldn't automatically generate the code because it treated the `addiu` as a low level literal instruction.

On the other hand, `mars` *does* treat this as a pseudo-op and generates:

```
    lui    $at,0
    ori    $at,$at,0xF000
    addu   $a0,$zero,$at
```

It recognizes that you want an *unsigned* operation, so it has to generate instructions that produce a true unsigned addition using `addu`

However, if you rewrite your original as:

```
    addu    $a0,$zero,0xF000
```

Now, `spim` *will* treat this as a pseudo-op and generate:

```
    ori     $a0,$zero,-4096
```

And, `mars` is happy with that rewrite as well